# Proving absolute value equations

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, absolute-value

How do I prove that for all real numbers $x$ and $y$ I have

```
|x + y| ≤ |x| + |y|

||x| − |y|| ≤ |x − y|

|xy| = |x||y|
```

I know the definition of absolute value tells me: for any real number $x$ we define $|x| = x$ if $x ≥ 0$ or $−x$ if $x < 0$

Comment: Assuming you are doing this for real numbers: worst case scenario for the first and third: prove it for each of the four cases: $x\geq 0, y\geq 0;~~x\geq 0, y<0;~~x<0,y\geq 0;~~x<0,y<0$.  For the second, use the first and some trickery.

Comment: I was posted in this site already. I think the best way is squaring of the both sides.